# Using LINQ to group by multiple properties and sum

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a collection of items, here it is:

```
AgencyID VendorID StateID Amount Fee
1        1        1       20.00  5.00
1        1        1       10.00  2.00
1        1        1       30.00  8.00    
2        2        1       20.00  5.00
2        2        1       5.00   5.00
1        1        2       20.00  5.00
2        2        2       20.00  5.00
2        2        2       40.00  9.00
1        2        2       35.00  6.00
1        2        2       12.00  3.00
```

I'd like these items to be grouped based on the AgencyID, VendorID, and StateID, and the Total calculated from Amount and Fee (Amount + Fee)

So using the data above, I'd like to have these results:

```
AgencyID VendorID StateID Total
1        1        1       75.00    
2        2        1       35.00
1        1        2       25.00
2        2        2       74.00
1        2        2       56.00
```

Here's all I have right now, which just gets every row in the database:

```
var agencyContracts = _agencyContractsRepository.AgencyContracts.
    Select(ac => new AgencyContractViewModel
    {
        AgencyContractId = ac.AgencyContractID,
        AgencyId = ac.AgencyID,
        VendorId = ac.VendorID,
        RegionId = ac.RegionID,
        Amount = ac.Amount,
        Fee = ac.Fee
    });
```

Does anyone know how I can filter and group this with LINQ?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use the `.Select()` after grouping:

```
var agencyContracts = _agencyContractsRepository.AgencyContracts
    .GroupBy(ac => new
                   {
                       ac.AgencyContractID, // required by your view model. should be omited
                                            // in most cases because group by primary key
                                            // makes no sense.
                       ac.AgencyID,
                       ac.VendorID,
                       ac.RegionID
                   })
    .Select(ac => new AgencyContractViewModel
                   {
                       AgencyContractID = ac.Key.AgencyContractID,
                       AgencyId = ac.Key.AgencyID,
                       VendorId = ac.Key.VendorID,
                       RegionId = ac.Key.RegionID,
                       Amount = ac.Sum(acs => acs.Amount),
                       Fee = ac.Sum(acs => acs.Fee)
                   });
```

Comment: I think you are missing the `Key`-property.

Comment: @MartinMulder: Thanks! You're right. Updated my code.

Answer (score 18):

Linus is spot on in the approach, but a few properties are off. It looks like 'AgencyContractId' is your Primary Key, which is unrelated to the output you want to give the user. I think this is what you want (assuming you change your ViewModel to match the data you say you want in your view).

```
var agencyContracts = _agencyContractsRepository.AgencyContracts
    .GroupBy(ac => new
                   {
                       ac.AgencyID,
                       ac.VendorID,
                       ac.RegionID
                   })
    .Select(ac => new AgencyContractViewModel
                   {
                       AgencyId = ac.Key.AgencyID,
                       VendorId = ac.Key.VendorID,
                       RegionId = ac.Key.RegionID,
                       Total = ac.Sum(acs => acs.Amount) + ac.Sum(acs => acs.Fee)
                   });
```