# How to sum up datagridview columns by unique id's?

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview

I have a datagridview which is populated with records from .csv file (around 30k records with 30-40 unique id's - depends on file). It looks like this:

Now my question is how to sum up those columns by id? Or maybe there is a way to directly put already sumed up values to datagridview?

```
private void dropListBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    data= new List<Raport>();
    string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        var nameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
        dropListBox.Items.Clear();
        dropListBox.Items.Add(nameOnly);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

        string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(file, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1250"));

        int i = 0;
        foreach (string line in readText)
        {
            if (i++ == 0) continue;
            var values = line.Split(';');

            string a= values[0];
            string b= values[1];
            string c= values[2];
            string user = values[3];
            int xValues= int.Parse(values[4]);
            int yValues= int.Parse(values[5]);
            double d= double.Parse(values[6]);
            string e= values[7];
            string f= values[8];
            string g= values[9];
            string h= values[10];
            double i= double.Parse(values[11]);
            string j= values[12];

            Raport Raport = new Raport(
                a,
                b,
                c,
                user,
                xValues,
                yValues,
                d,
                e,
                f,
                g,
                h,
                i,
                j);

            data.Add(Raport);

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Raport.user, Raport.xValues, Raport.yValues, "8", "8");
```

This is the code I have. The last 2 columns doesn't matter (It's always filled with fixed values)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

It should go like this

```
John |   5   |     4    
Carl |   3   |     1  
John |   1   |     6  
Carl |   4   |     1
```

then

```
John |   6   |  10  
Carl |   7   |   2
```

the structure of the Raport Class

```
class Raport
{
    public readonly string a;
    public readonly string b;
    public readonly string c;
    public readonly string user;
    public readonly int xValue;
    public readonly int yValue;
    public readonly double d;
    public readonly string e;
    public readonly string f;
    public readonly string g;
    public readonly string h;
    public readonly double i;
    public readonly string j;

    public Raport(
        string a,
        string b,
        string c,
        string user,
        int xValue,
        int yValue,
        double d,
        string e,
        string f,
        string g,
        string h,
        double i,
        string j)
    {
        this.a= a;
        this.b= b;
        this.c= c;
        this.user= user;
        this.xValue= xValue;
        this.yValue= yValue;
        this.d= d;
        this.e= e;
        this.f= f;
        this.g= g;
        this.h= h;
        this.i= i;
        this.j= j;
    }

    public Raport()
    {
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return  a+ " ; " + 
            b+ " ; " +
            c+ " ; " +
            user+ " ; " +
            xValue+ " ; " +
            yValue+ " ; " +
            d+ " ; " +
            e+ " ; " +
            f+ " ; " + 
            g+ " ; " +
            h+ " ; " +
            i+ " ; " +
            j;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Which of these columns 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j' is the ID one? And what is the structure of the class Raport? What fields do you want to sum?

Comment: ID is the "user" one, the values I want to sum up is xValues and yValues based on the ID.(I put them in datagridview in this line: dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Raport.user, Raport.xValues, Raport.yValues, "8", "8"); )
 The  'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j' doesn't matter but the exist in .csv file which I put to the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you're already adding every `Raport` object to a list *and* the DataGridView:

```
data= new List<Raport>();
// ...
data.Add(Raport);
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Raport.user, Raport.xValues, Raport.yValues, "8", "8");
```

You can utilize this list and LINQ to your advantage to group your objects by the `user` property, summing the other two needed properties, [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15605586/3773066).  This will be stored into another list, which can then be used to fill your DataGridView:

```
var summedData = data.GroupBy(r => new { r.user })
                     .Select(r => new Raport()
                                  {
                                      user = r.Key.user,
                                      xValue = r.Sum(innerR => innerR.xValue),
                                      yValue = r.Sum(innerR => innerR.yValue)
                                  }
                             );
```

Then, instead of adding each `Raport` created during creation of your original `data`list, just loop through the new summed list:

```
foreach (Raport raport in summedData)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(raport.user, raport.xValues, raport.yValues, "8", "8");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and effort to make it.