# Group a teacher list by School Board and School

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, lambda

I have query that return a list of Teachers and I need to group them by School Board and School.

Actually a show the data like bellow:

```
School Board Name 1
School Name 1
Teacher Name 1

School Board Name 1
School Name 1
Teacher Name 2

School Board Name 1
School Name 2
Teacher Name 3

School Board Name 1
School Name 2
Teacher Name 4
```

What I need to show:

```
School Board Name 1
School Name 1
Teacher Name 1
Teacher Name 2

School Board Name 1
School Name 2
Teacher Name 3
Teacher Name 4
```

I'm trying using Linq or Lambda to make this, I don't know if this is the best way.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231845/c-sharp-linq-group-by-on-multiple-columns), for example.

Comment: What code do you currently have, and how does it behave?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group your entities by composite key - i.e. use new anonymous type to group teachers by school board name and school name:

```
var query = teachers.GroupBy(t => new { t.SchoolBoardName, t.SchoolName });

foreach(var schoolGroup in query)
{
   Console.WriteLine(schoolGroup.Key.SchoolBoardName);
   Console.WriteLine(schoolGroup.Key.SchoolName);

   foreach(var teacher in schoolGroup)
        Console.WriteLine(teacher.TeacherName);
}
```