# LINQ & Grouping data by a date range

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Say I have the below set of data where I wish to group the Description column based on whether the dates for matching Descriptions are within a few seconds of each other.

[image]

The output I'm looking for is the Description and the minimum Date for that group. It is possible that the Description could be the same but the dates might be days different, in this case I would want two outputted rows.

In the case above take a look at the Description "TEST s" where I would want two outputted grouped rows

TEST  s 2014-12-04 16:27:44.903

TEST  s 2014-12-04 17:21:21.233

Is this possible using Linq?

Comment: so you want multiple group bys? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231845/c-sharp-linq-group-by-on-multiple-columns

Comment: @Ric More of a Group, Min in TSQL terms but with separate lines where the dates are out of a range. To be honest I'm not sure how to term this in TSQL.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to group rows that are "within a few seconds of each other".  The example you have the dates are the same within each group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var q = from item in lstMyTable
        group item by item.ItemDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm") into ItemGroup
        select new
        {
            Description = ItemGroup.First().Description,
            Date = ItemGroup.OrderBy(x => x.ItemDate).First().ItemDate
        };
```

The above linq query groups by date + hour + minutes, ignoring seconds. The `OrderBy` applied to `ItemGroup` ensures that we get the *mininum* date, as described in the OP.

With this input:

```
List<MyTable> lstMyTable = new List<MyTable>()
{
  new MyTable() { Description = "TEST s", ItemDate = new DateTime(2014, 12, 4, 16, 27, 11) },
  new MyTable() { Description = "TEST s", ItemDate = new DateTime(2014, 12, 4, 16, 27, 12) },
  new MyTable() { Description = "TEST s", ItemDate = new DateTime(2014, 12, 4, 16, 27, 13) },

  new MyTable() { Description = "TEST s", ItemDate = new DateTime(2014, 12, 4, 17, 21, 11) },
  new MyTable() { Description = "TEST s", ItemDate = new DateTime(2014, 12, 4, 17, 21, 12) },
  new MyTable() { Description = "TEST s", ItemDate = new DateTime(2014, 12, 4, 17, 21, 13) }
};
```

you get this result:

```
[0] = { Description = "TEST s", Date = {4/12/2014 4:27:11 pm} }
[1] = { Description = "TEST s", Date = {4/12/2014 5:21:11 pm} }
```

If you want to also group by description then simply substitue the `group by` clause with sth like this:

```
group item by new 
{ 
   a = item.ItemDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm") ,
   b = item.Description 
} into ItemGroup
```

Finally, by converting the `Datetime` field to `Ticks`, you can fiddle with the required time distance between separate records, e.g.

```
group item by new 
{ 
    a = item.ItemDate.Ticks.ToString().Substring(0, item.ItemDate.Ticks.ToString().Length - 10), // instead of .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm") ,
    b = item.Description 
} into ItemGroup
```

You can play around by varying the number of digits subtracted from `item.ItemDate.Ticks`, substituting e.g. 10 with 9 or 8, etc.

Comment: I believe the OP wants to also group by the Description.

Comment: @juharr well, i focused on the case he describes. My sample data are based on that case.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos That's close enough to what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want left hand side to be a list then you can try this

```
var query = (from t in db.Table
             group t by new {t.Description, t.Date }
             into grp
             select new
             {
                 grp.Key.Description,
                 grp.Key.Date,                        
             }).ToList();
```