# Group by in LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a scenario where I am getting a data table with the following values:

```
 UserId   DeptId deptname  DependentName
  1          45     test       test1
  1          45     test       test2
  1          45     test       test3
  2          46     y          firstName
  2          46     y          firstName1
  2          46     y          firstName2
```

I need a LINQ query where I need to get one to get in the following format:

```
user id = 1
deptid = 45 
deptname = test

DependentName = {test1,tes2,test3}

user id = 2
deptid = 46 
deptname = y

DependentName = {firstName,firstName1,firstName2}
```

Comment: So, you want to get `DependentName` as a comma separated string. Am i right?

Comment: dependentName in a collection

Comment: I bet he didn't even try. if he google linq101, he would've gotten the answer.

Comment: FYI..i tried and then came to help site but the value for dependent is not grouping and still trying it.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is a problem?

```
var result = ctx.Entity.GroupBy(u => new { 
   u.UserId,
   u.DeptId,
   u.DeptName
}).ToList().Select(grouped => new { 
    GroupKey = grouped.Key,
    DeptNames => string.Join(",", grouped.Select(gr => gr.DependentName)) 
});
```

Comment: `ToList()` after `GroupBy` is redundant!

Comment: @MaciejLos No. If it is Entity Framework context, `string.Join` will fail without `ToList()`.

Comment: I am using datatable as enumerable hence i am failing to get it

Comment: Instead of `ToList` you can use `AsEnumerable`.

Comment: Thank you, solved the issue i missed to select the resultset from grouped items. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Based on MSDN :

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TElement>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector
)
```

This should look like this :

```
melist.GroupBy(e = > new { e.UserId, e.DeptId, e.Deptname }, e);
```

This question was already answered here:
[C# Linq Group By on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231845/c-sharp-linq-group-by-on-multiple-columns)