# Group by on multiple columns and trace values which are not distinct

Tags: c#, list, linq, object, collections

I have a collection which has items like 
InstId, PulseID and SheetID on top of other items. I would like to check if these values (as a combination) in the collection are distinct if they are not I would like to output them a simple trace message "Not Unique: InstId, PulseID and SheetID.

For e.g.,

```
InstId  |   PulseID     |   SheetID     |
-----------------------------------------
    1   |   1           |   99          |
    1   |   1           |   98          |
    1   |   1           |   97          |
    2   |   1           |   99          |
    2   |   1           |   98          |
    3   |   1           |   97          |
    2   |   1           |   99          |
    2   |   1           |   95          |
    3   |   1           |   93          |


    I would like a trace message which will output the duplicatite like 
    InstId:2, PulseID: 1, SheetID: 99
```

I was looking through this link and it seems to make sense but how do i get the ones which are not unique.
[C# Linq Group By on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231845/c-sharp-linq-group-by-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: just show us what you  have tried

Comment: Can you give a (short) example of the data and the expected result.

Comment: I have updated my question to show my collection and the result I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for something like this?

```
var result = IQueryableSource.GroupBy(x=>new {A=x.A, B=x.B, C=x.C}).Where(x=>x.Count()>1).Select(x=>x.Key);
```

Comment: I am new to Linq, I cant quite understand what is x.key. I will try and implement this on my collection and see if it works. Cheers.

Comment: It would have been more readable as `elements.GroupBy(element => new { A = element.A, B = element.B }).Where(group => group.Count() > 1).Select(group => group.Key)`. Then it becomes (at least a little more) clear that `group.Key` is the anonymous object `{ A = element.A, B = element.B }` that you group by.

Comment: This works perfectly fine.  I have converted it to a list before using so that I can loop through.  Solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the link uses query syntax, how about

```
var ans = from item in CollectionOfItems 
          group item by new { item.InstId, item.PulseID, item.SheetID } into ig
          where ig.Count() > 1
          select ig.Key;
```

You could also `select ig.First()` if you wanted the original collection item.

Comment: Thank you. The simpler version is @DarkSquirrel42 answer.