# LINQ filter Elements based on two properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of string of unique keys

```
  var uniqueKeys = new List<string>   {"01", "04", "09", "26", "27"};
```

I am trying to filter another list based on these unique keys.

Data in the list can be seen like this :

```
To  From    
01  05
01  02
09  04
01  09
01  45
04  06
27  12
```

I want to select data from this list in a way that both "To" and "From" property values lies in uniqueKeys

**Desired Result should be :**

```
To  From
09  04
01  09
```

I have been through many posts over internet an I am not able to write the logic in simple LINQ format.

If someone has faced this problem please help me.

Comment: Grouping by two columns ? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231845/c-sharp-linq-group-by-on-multiple-columns) might help

Comment: Is your list to be filtered a list of custom objects or a dictionary?

Comment: What you're asking is impossible with List<string> in LINQ, you should be using List<Tuple<string,string>>

Comment: Not a dictionary, List of a class having two properties. @ChrisPickford

Comment: What's wrong with AND operation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets say your list of class name is "listToFrom". You can use the && operator on both the properties to get the desired list.

```
var filteredList = listToFrom.Where(x=>uniqueKeys.Contains(x.To) && 
                    uniqueKeys.Contains(x.From)).ToList();
```

Comment: You're missing a `)` before `.ToList()`

Comment: Thanks @JakubDąbek. Corrected :)

Answer (score 3):

You can put several statements in a `.Where` so you can filter on multiple fields, the key in this case is `.Contains`.

```
//Making test data
List<Example> dataList = new List<Example>()
{
    new Example() { From = "05", To = "01" },
    new Example() { From = "02", To = "01" },
    new Example() { From = "04", To = "09" },
    new Example() { From = "09", To = "01" },
    new Example() { From = "45", To = "01" },
    new Example() { From = "06", To = "04" },
    new Example() { From = "12", To = "27" }
};
var uniqueKeys = new List<string> { "01", "04", "09", "26", "27" };

//Filter data
var filteredList = dataList
                    .Where( row => uniqueKeys.Contains( row.To ) && 
                                    uniqueKeys.Contains( row.From ) )
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.Contains` to check if a collection contains an item. Also, you can utilize LINQ `.Where` to filter a collection with specified condition.

```
var uniqueKeys = new List<string> {"01", "04", "09", "26", "27"};
var result = data
    .Where(x => uniqueKeys.Contains(x.From) && uniqueKeys.Contains(x.To)) 
    .ToArray();
```

Another one thing which should be kept in mind - this algorithm is linear, i.e. it will iterate `uniqueKeys` every time to check if it contains a value. 
Performance can be improved by using `HashSet` which provides `O(1)` `.Contains` check.

```
var uniqueKeys = new List<string> {"01", "04", "09", "26", "27"};
var uniqueKeysSet = new HashSet<string>(uniqueKeys);
var result = data
    .Where(x => uniqueKeysSet.Contains(x.From) && uniqueKeysSet.Contains(x.To)) 
    .ToArray();
```

However, you can skip this performance improvement if the number of items in `uniqueKeys` is small. It will overcomplicate code without necessity.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by combining two `.Contains()` LINQ clauses as follows:

```
var uniqueKeys = new List<string>   {"01", "04", "09", "26", "27"};

var data = new List<Tuple<string, string>> {
new Tuple<string, string>("01", "05"),
new Tuple<string, string>("01", "02"),
new Tuple<string, string>("09", "04"),
new Tuple<string, string>("01", "09"),
new Tuple<string, string>("01", "45"),
new Tuple<string, string>("04", "06"),
new Tuple<string, string>("27", "12")
};

var results = data.Where(d => uniqueKeys.Contains(d.Item1) && uniqueKeys.Contains(d.Item2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    var uniqueKeys = new List<string>   {"01", "04", "09", "26", "27"};


    List<Example> filtedvalues = Maindatas.FindAll(emp => uniqueKeys == emp.to && uniqueKeys == emp.from);
```