# Group by two columns in linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, collections

[image]

Hi 
I want to group the above list of stores in this case.
The above is a `List(of Stores)` and I want create a new list of stores where they are all grouped by `FromStore` and `ToStore`.

Example:

```
Dim Test As List(Of Stores) = MyTStores.GroupBy(Function(x) x.ToStore).[Select](Function(grp) grp.First()).ToList()
```

This example only group by one columns and not two.

Comment: Are you looking as mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231845/c-sharp-linq-group-by-on-multiple-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.GroupBy(Function(X) New With {X.FromStore, X.ToStore})
```

or just this, if you do not care about the key in next processing:

```
.GroupBy(Function(X) X.FromStore & "-" & X.ToStore)
```